# MySQL COM_EXECUTE_STMT fails with error but the error does not make sense

Tags: mysql, database, networking, database-connection

I'm sending a COM_EXECUTE_STMT message and the server always returns an:

> Error 1048 - #23000 - Column 'number_tinyint' cannot be null

The query is like this:

```
insert into numbers (
number_tinyint,
number_smallint,
number_mediumint,
number_int,
number_bigint,
number_decimal,
number_float,
number_double
) values
(
?, 679, 778, 875468, 100007654, 198.657809, 432.8, ?)
```

And what I send in is:

```
0: 18 00 00 00 17 01 00 00     . . . . . . . .
1: 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00     . . . . . . . .
2: 01 01 05 0a 29 5c 8f c2     . . . . ) \ . .
3: f5 b0 58 40                 . . X @
```

And simplified for reading:

```
18 00 00 - size
00 - sequence
17 - type
01 00 00 00 - statement id
00 - flags
01 00 00 00 - iteration-count
00 00 - null bitmap
01 - new params bound flag
01 - byte type
05 - double type
0a - byte value - 10
29 5c 8f c2 f5 b0 58 40 - double value
```

The statement parameters are 10 (for the tinyint column) and 98.765 (for the double column). From what I can see the message is encoded correctly but it always fails for some reason ([at least from what the documentation says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/prepared-statements.html#com-stmt-execute))

Am I missing something in here?

Comment: Shouldn't your null bitmap be 1 byte long: (2+7)/8 = 9/8 = 1?

Comment: good question, let me try that.

Comment: holy mother of christ @eggyal! that was it! can you please answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation to which you've linked:

```
  payload:
[ deletia ]
    n              NULL-bitmap, length: (num-params+7)/8
```

Therefore, with two parameters in your case, the NULL-bitmap should have a length of (2+7)/8 = 1 byte, whereas you currently have a 2-byte bitmap.